# Node HTTPS Remote Server

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am trying to deploy my node app on a remote server. I have a domain and the corresponding SSL keys.

```
const app = express();
const options = {
    key: readFileSync('mykey'),
    cert: readFileSync('mykey'),
};
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on Port ${port}`);
});
```

netstat on `443`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5768/node
```

So the app works fine if I listen on port 443. That is, can access my app through `https://example.com`.

However, if I try to listen on another port, my browser tells me the connection is refused. The only

netstat checked on port '5000':

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6243/node
```

It seems it is listening on port 5000, however, I cannot access `https://example.com:5000`.
I am confused about it. Is it possible that there are some firewall settings on my Linux server that block port 5000? Or is there somewhere I should do alternatively?

Comment: Is the remote server firewalled?

Comment: Either the network is blocking the port, or the server's firewall.

Comment: @Quentin Is there an easy way to check it?

Comment: @Zak What do you mean by 'the network is blocking the port,' my browser, or something else? I think DNS is not a part of this and the request should be sent to the server.

Comment: @jeffma — The hosting service's documentation?

Comment: @Quentin Based on my understanding, I have 'Allows: All traffic for all ports' set up on the hosting service. Before I tried to use a proxy pass on nginx to reverse 8000 to my app and it worked. So I think the server is unlikely to be firewalled.

Comment: @Zak Thank you for your help! It is the firewall's problem. I assumed it was the hosting service's network settings, but actually, I did not open the firewall on my server machine.